# How to use Object.prototype.valueOf to differ return type as a result of coercion in equal value and equal type operator?

Tags: javascript

```
A question says to make a sum function that meets the required output as:
```

My question is, under the circumstance, is it possible to reach the result?

```js
const sum1 = sum(1)
sum1(2)() // return 3
sum1(3)() // return 4

// call directly without assigning to a variable
sum(1)(2)(3)() // return 6
sum(5)(-1)(2)() // return 6

sum(1)(2)(4) == 7 // true
sum(1)(2)(4) === 7 // false
```

And the definition to the `sum` function:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} num
 */
function sum(num) {
  // your code here
}
```

It also hints that a decent understand of [Object.prototype.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is crucial.

I write something like the code below, also a script for testing and to show my perspective about the required returns. I think `Object.prototype.valueOf` works when I call the return for as a primitive type, especially a value. (Refers to [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-type-conversion))

My opinion about the question are:

1. To meet the test case - `sum(1)(2)(4) == 7 -> true`, `useSum.prototype.valueOf` is necessary, but I found that I have to call `new` for make it work. However, this operation also results an `object` instead of a function.
2. Then I use conditionals to return function if there is an argument or to return plain value.
3. While I passed some test cases, the test case - `sum(1)(2)(4) == 7 -> true` turn to be failed.
4. I also failed in the cases to run `sum1(3)() === 4` after running `sum1(2)() === 3`. The `this.accumulator` does not know that it's came from `sum1` which has an initial base of 1.
5. Dealing with the problem than raising another problem for `this.accumulator` leaves value that affect the initial value in calc the test cases: `sum(1)(2)(3)() === 6`, `sum(5)(-1)(2)() === 6`.

```js
/**
 * @param {number} num 
 */
function sum(num = 0) {
    if (this.accumulator) {
        this.accumulator += num;
    } else {
        this.accumulator = num;
        this.init = num;
    }
    const that = this
    function useSum(isEnd) {
        if (!isEnd) {
            return (addend) => sum(addend)
        }
        return that.accumulator
    }
    if (num) {
        useSum.prototype.valueOf = function() {
            return that.accumulator;
        }
        const result = new useSum(false);
        return result
    }
    const result = this.accumulator;
    this.accumulator = 0;
    return result
}


// test function
function expect(caseName, occasion) {
    function toBe(result) {
        console.log(`test case: ${caseName}`);
        if (occasion === result) {
            console.log("--> pass\n")
        } else {
            console.log(`--> fail, expect ${result}, got ${occasion}\n`)
        }
        return null
    }
    return { toBe }
}

// test cases from my pespective
const sum1 = sum(1);
expect("sum1(2)() === 3", sum1(2)()).toBe(3)
expect("sum1(3)() === 4", sum1(3)()).toBe(4)
expect("sum(1)(2)(3)() === 6", sum(1)(2)(3)()).toBe(6)
expect("sum(5)(-1)(2)() === 6", sum(5)(-1)(2)()).toBe(6)
expect("sum(1)(2)(4) == 7 -> true", sum(1)(2)(4) == 7).toBe(true)
expect("sum(1)(2)(4) === 7 -> false", sum(1)(2)(4) === 7).toBe(false)
```

My appreciation for any article, idea for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to point out what specifically you should change in you answer to make it work. When I look at the question at hand my mind immediately jumps to a recursive function that uses variable/parameter scoping to store the values.

```js
const sum1 = sum(1)
console.log(sum1(2)()) // return 3
console.log(sum1(3)()) // return 4

// call directly without assigning to a variable
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)()) // return 6
console.log(sum(5)(-1)(2)()) // return 6

console.log(sum(1)(2)(4) == 7) // true
console.log(sum(1)(2)(4) === 7) // false

function sum(a) {
  if (!arguments.length) return;

  function addA(b) {
    if (!arguments.length) return a;
    return sum(a + b);
  };
  
  Object.defineProperty(addA, "valueOf", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value() { return a },
  });
  
  return addA;
}
```

In the answer above `!arguments.length` in `sumA` is used to check if parameters are passed. If no parameters are passed `a` is returned, which holds the final sum value.

If there there is a parameter present `sum(a + b)` is returned which in turn returns a new `addA` function. This new function has it's `a` argument updated to hold the new value.

After creating the function `sumA` we give it a custom [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method that returns the current sum, this is used for type coercion. This is needed to let `sum(1)(2)(4) == 7` evaluate properly. I've added this property as a non-enumerable property using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), but it can be simplified if you don't mind `valueOf` being enumerable.

To use an enumerable property change:

```js
Object.defineProperty(addA, "valueOf", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value() { return a },
});
```

Into:

```js
addA.valueOf = () => a;
```

```js
const sum1 = sum(1)
console.log(sum1(2)()) // return 3
console.log(sum1(3)()) // return 4

// call directly without assigning to a variable
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)()) // return 6
console.log(sum(5)(-1)(2)()) // return 6

console.log(sum(1)(2)(4) == 7) // true
console.log(sum(1)(2)(4) === 7) // false

function sum(a) {
  if (!arguments.length) return;

  function addA(b) {
    if (!arguments.length) return a;
    return sum(a + b);
  };
  
  addA.valueOf = () => a;
  
  return addA;
}
```

Note that a function can be treated as a normal JavaScript object and can be assigned properties like `valueOf`, or any other property for that matter.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that the `defineProperty` can do this. It turned out I changed to the prototype and use `this` made things more complicated.

Comment: You don't *need* `defineProperty`. Like I stated in the answer, a simple `addA.valueOf = () => a` would work as well. However that creates an enumerable property instead of a non-enumerable property.